# Protocol not implemented in 'AllListsViewController.m'; other errors

Tags: ios, objective-c

Am having protocol errors in AllListsViewController.m, but can't figure out why. Also have some other errors which I have commented out.

AllListsViewController.m

```
#import "AllListsViewController.h"
#import "ChecklistViewController.h"
#import "Checklist.h"
#import "ChecklistItem.h"

@interface AllListsViewController ()

@end

@implementation AllListsViewController
/* Method 'listDetailViewController:didFinishAddingChecklist' in protocol not  implemented
   Method 'listDetailViewController:didFinishEditingChecklist' in protocol not implemented
   Method 'listDetailViewControllerDidCancel:' in protocol not implemented
 */
{
    NSMutableArray *_lists;
}

-(NSString *)documentsDirectory
{
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths firstObject];
    return documentsDirectory;
}

-(NSString *)dataFilePath
{
    return [[self documentsDirectory] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Checklists.plist"];
}

-(void)saveChecklistItems
{
    NSMutableData *data = [[NSMutableData alloc] init];
    NSKeyedArchiver *archiver = [[NSKeyedArchiver alloc] initForWritingWithMutableData:data];
    [archiver encodeObject:_lists forKey:@"Checklists"];
    [archiver finishEncoding];
    [data writeToFile:[self dataFilePath] atomically:YES];
}

-(void)loadChecklists
{
    NSString *path = [self dataFilePath];
    if ([[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:path]) {
        NSData *data = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:path];
        NSKeyedUnarchiver *unarchiver = [[NSKeyedUnarchiver alloc] initForReadingWithData:data];

        _lists = [unarchiver decodeObjectForKey:@"Checklists"];
        [unarchiver finishDecoding];

    } else {
        _lists = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:20];
    }
}

-(id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder
{
    if ((self = [super initWithCoder:aDecoder])) {

        _lists = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:20];

        Checklist *list;

        list = [[Checklist alloc] init];
        list.name = @"Birthdays";
        [_lists addObject:list];

        list = [[Checklist alloc] init];
        list.name = @"Groceries";
        [_lists addObject:list];

        list = [[Checklist alloc] init];
        list.name = @"Cool Apps";
        [_lists addObject:list];

        list = [[Checklist alloc] init];
        list.name = @"To Do";
        [_lists addObject:list];

        for (Checklist *list in _lists) {
            ChecklistItem *item = [[ChecklistItem alloc] init];
            item.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Item for %@", list.name];
            [list.items addObject:item];
        [self loadChecklists];
        }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad // Use of undeclared identifier 'viewDidLoad'
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    // Uncomment the following line to preserve selection between presentations.
    // self.clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear = NO;

    // Uncomment the following line to display an Edit button in the navigation bar for this view controller.
    // self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem;
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

#pragma mark - Table view data source

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{

    // Return the number of rows in the section.
    return [_lists count];
}


- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    // Configure the cell...

    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault
                                      reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    }

    Checklist *checklist = _lists[indexPath.row];
    cell.textLabel.text = checklist.name;
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDetailDisclosureButton;

    return cell;
}

-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    Checklist *checklist = _lists[indexPath.row];
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"ShowChecklist" sender:checklist];
}

#pragma mark - Table View Delegate Protocol


/*
// Override to support conditional editing of the table view.
- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canEditRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    // Return NO if you do not want the specified item to be editable.
    return YES;
}
*/


// Override to support editing the table view.
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    [_lists removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    NSArray *indexPaths = @[indexPath];
    [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:indexPaths withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];
}


/*
// Override to support rearranging the table view.
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView moveRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)fromIndexPath toIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)toIndexPath
{
}
*/

/*
// Override to support conditional rearranging of the table view.
- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canMoveRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    // Return NO if you do not want the item to be re-orderable.
    return YES;
}
*/


#pragma mark - Navigation

// In a storyboard-based application, you will often want to do a little preparation before navigation
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"ShowChecklist"]) {
        ChecklistViewController *controller = segue.destinationViewController;
        controller.checklist = sender;
    }
    else if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"AddChecklist"]) {
        UINavigationController *navigationController = segue.destinationViewController;

        ListDetailViewController *controller = (ListDetailViewController *)navigationController.topViewController;

        controller.delegate = self;
        controller.checklistToEdit = nil;
    }
}

-(void)listDetailViewControllerDidCancel:(ListDetailViewController *)controller
{
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}

-(void)listDetailViewController:(ListDetailViewController *)controller didFinishAddingChecklist:(Checklist *)checklist
{
    NSInteger newRowIndex = [_lists count];
    [_lists addObject:checklist];

    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:newRowIndex inSection:0];

    NSArray *indexPaths = @[indexPath];
    [self.tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:indexPaths withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}

-(void)listDetailViewController:(ListDetailViewController *)controller didFinishEditingChecklist:(Checklist *)checklist
{
    NSInteger index = [_lists indexOfObject:checklist];
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:index inSection:0];

    UITableViewCell *cell = [self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    cell.textLabel.text = checklist.name;

    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}

-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView accessoryButtonTappedForRowWithIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UINavigationController *navigationController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ListNavigationController"];

    ListDetailViewController *controller = (ListDetailViewController *)navigationController.topViewController;

    controller.delegate = self;

    Checklist *checklist = _lists[indexPath.row];
    controller.checklistToEdit = checklist;

    [self presentViewController:navigationController animated:YES completion:nil];
}

@end // Missing "end" | Expected "}"
```

AllListsViewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "ListDetailViewController.h"

@interface AllListsViewController : UITableViewController <ListDetailViewControllerDelegate>

@end
```

ListDetailViewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@class ListDetailViewController;
@class Checklist;

@protocol ListDetailViewControllerDelegate <NSObject>

-(void)listDetailViewControllerDidCancel:(ListDetailViewController *)controller;

-(void)listDetailViewController:(ListDetailViewController *)controller didFinishAddingChecklist:(Checklist *)checklist;

-(void)listDetailViewController:(ListDetailViewController *)controller didFinishEditingChecklist:(Checklist *)checklist;

@end

@interface ListDetailViewController : UITableViewController

@property (nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet UITextField *textField;
@property (nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet UIBarButtonItem *doneBarButton;

@property (nonatomic, weak) id <ListDetailViewControllerDelegate> delegate;
@property (nonatomic, strong) Checklist *checklistToEdit;

-(IBAction)cancel;
-(IBAction)done;

@end
```

Comment: you are missing a `}` in your `initWithCoder:` method, specifically the closing brace for the `if`.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the fact that you are getting errors about a missing end and "expected '}', it sounds like you have mismatched curly brackets in your code. This sort of thing is really hard to spot by looking at code, but quite easy in Xcode. double-tap on each opening curly brace and Xcode will select the entire contents of the block up to the closing brace. Do that in your AllListsViewController.m file until you find the opening curly brace that does not have a corresponding closing brace.